# Why does CA_LAYER_SURFACE=0 improve core animation performance?

Tags: macos, core-animation

I'm building a scrolling intensive app for macOS with core animation. I've been using [CA Instrument](http://jwilling.com/blog/debugging-core-animation-on-osx/) to help with optimization. While doing this I noticed something odd... my app gets a better frame rate when running under the CA Instrument debugging tool then it does when running normally.

I found the underlying reason is that the CA Instrument tool sets the CA_LAYER_SURFACE environment variable to 0. Doing that changes the codepath that cocoa uses to render core animation layers, and as a result my app goes from 55fps to 60fps and has noticeably smoother scrolling.

Can anyone tell me more about this CA_LAYER_SURFACE flag. From the above linked to article is seems that including it enables old behavior. But if that's the case why was the old behavior replaced with a new slower behavior? What are the tradeoffs if I decide to leave this flag set to CA_LAYER_SURFACE=0 in my production app?

Thanks!

**update**

Most of the performance increase went away (i.e. both versions are fast) once I changed the way that I create offscreen rendering contexts as described here:

[Fastest way to draw offscreen CALayer content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46029519/fastest-way-to-draw-offscreen-calayer-content)

I've also found out a bit more about the flag as describe in the answer that I posted below.

Answer (score 1):

These release notes (search for "Changes to layer rendering") explain what the flag does:

[AppKit Release Notes – Changes to layer rendering](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/releasenotes/AppKit/RN-AppKitOlderNotes/index.html#X10_9Notes)

The flag itself isn't document. But setting `NSView.layerUsesCoreImageFilters` to `true` has the same effect: rendering your layers in process instead of out of process which is the new default.

I don't fully understand the tradeoffs, but for me the takeaway is that you don't need to use the undocumented CA_LAYER_SURFACE flag, instead just set `NSView.layerUsesCoreImageFilters`.